# How to set the locale in RSpec View Examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I want to test the view to make sure that error messages are properly rendered. My `config.default_locale` is `'fr'`. So, I expect my view to find the proper Active Record error message from my french locale file.

```
describe 'book/new.html.erb' do
  let(:subject) { rendered }
  before do
    @book = Book.create #this generates errors on my model
    render
  end
  it { should match 'some error message in French' }
end
```

This test passes when ran in isolation or with the other spec/views. But when I run the full test suite the view gets rendered with the message:`translation missing: en.activerecord.errors.models.book.attributes.title.blank`.

I don't understand why it renders with an `en` locale. I tried to force the locale with:

```
before do
  allow(I18n).to receive(:locale).and_return(:fr)
  allow(I18n).to receive(:default_locale).and_return(:fr)
end
```

and

```
before do
  default_url_options[:locale] = 'fr'
end
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what version of RSpec and Rails you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly address your issue with your view spec, but what I am suggesting could potentially solve your problem.

To test the actual error message, I wouldn't use a view spec. Instead, I would use a Model spec with [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) to test that a Book must have a title, and that the appropriate error message is used:

```
describe Book do
  it do
    is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:title).
      with_message I18n.t('activerecord.errors.models.book.attributes.title.blank')
  end
end
```

To test that an error message is displayed to the user when they try to create a Book without a title, I would use an integration test with [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) that looks something like this:

```
feature 'Create a book' do
  scenario 'without a title' do
    visit new_book_path
    fill_in 'title', with: ''
    click_button 'Submit'

    expect(page).
     to have_content I18n.t('activerecord.errors.models.book.attributes.title.blank')
  end
end
```

The advantage of using the locale key in the test is that if you ever change the actual text, your tests will still pass. Otherwise, if you were testing for the actual text, you would have to update your tests every time you changed the text.

In addition to that, it's also a good idea to raise an error in case the translation is missing by adding the following line to your `config/environments/test.rb`:

```
config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
```

Note that the above line requires Rails 4.1 or higher.

If you expect to be testing a lot of locales, you can add this helper to your RSpec configuration so that you can just use `t('some.locale.key')` instead of always having to type `I18n.t`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include AbstractController::Translation
end
```